# Rust manual memory management

Tags: memory-management, rust

When I began learning C,  I implemented common data structures such as lists, maps and trees. I used `malloc`, `calloc`, `realloc` and `free` to manage the memory manually when requested. I did the same thing with C++, using `new` and `delete`.

Now comes Rust. It seems like Rust doesn't offer any functions or operators which correspond to the ones of C or C++, at least in the stable release.

Are the [`Heap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/heap/struct.Heap.html) structure and the [`ptr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/) module (marked with `experimental`) the ones to look at for this kind of thing?

I know that these data structures are already in the language. It's for the sake of learning.

Comment: Manual allocation is deep into unsafe Rust territorry, it's covered pretty well in the [Rustonomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/nomicon/intro.html)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's very unusual to directly access the memory allocator in Rust. You generally want to use the smart pointer constructors (`Box::new`, `Rc::new`, `Arc::new`) for single objects and just use `Vec` or `Box<[T]>` if you want a heap-based array.

If you really want to allocate memory and get a raw pointer to it, you can look at the implementation of `Rc`. (Not `Box`. `Box` is magical.) To get its backing memory, it actually creates a `Box` and then uses its `into_raw_non_null` function to get the raw pointer out. For destroying, it uses the allocator API, but could alternatively use `Box::from_raw` and then `drop` that.

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: Then first you make absolutely sure it can't be implemented in terms of the existing ones. And in the unlikely case that that's really so, you can either use the allocator API, or use malloc from the libc crate.

Comment: Note that the Rust standard library for stable Rust can use unstable features internally, and as such is privileged over normal code.

Comment: Doron, just because I like to do so. I certainly don't aim to use my own in production.

Comment: @SebastianRedl could you explain the "magic" of Box? Sounds interesting!

Comment: @LppEdd https://manishearth.github.io/blog/2017/01/10/rust-tidbits-box-is-special/

Comment: Very good answer since it does not require libc and can be done in memory safe terms with only two unsafe wrapper functions.

Answer (score 32):

Although it's really not recommended to do this ever, you can use `malloc` and `free` like you are used to from C. It's not very useful, but here's how it looks:

```
extern crate libc; // 0.2.65

use std::mem;

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        let my_num: *mut i32 = libc::malloc(mem::size_of::<i32>() as libc::size_t) as *mut i32;
        if my_num.is_null() {
            panic!("failed to allocate memory");
        }
        libc::free(my_num as *mut libc::c_void);
    }
}
```

A better approach is to use Rust's standard library:

```
use std::alloc::{alloc, dealloc, Layout};

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        let layout = Layout::new::<u16>();
        let ptr = alloc(layout);

        *(ptr as *mut u16) = 42;
        assert_eq!(*(ptr as *mut u16), 42);

        dealloc(ptr, layout);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not necessarily should you "only use it if you want to create your own smart pointer".

Comment: It's omcprrect to say you should never do this, amlloc is slow and real time systems often allocate their own memory by first a single call to malloc and then managing their own memory.

Answer (score 19):

> Are the `Heap` structure and the `ptr` module (marked with experimental) the ones to look at for this kind of thing?

No, as a beginner you absolutely shouldn't start there. When you started learning C, `malloc` was all there was, and it's still a hugely error-prone part of the language - but you can't write any non-trivial program without it. It's very important for C programmers to learn about `malloc` and how to avoid all the pitfalls (memory leaks, use-after-free, and so on).

In modern C++, people are taught to use *smart pointers* to manage memory, instead of using `delete` by hand, but you still need to call `new` to allocate the memory for your smart pointer to manage. It's a lot better, but there's still some risk there. And still, as a C++ programmer, you need to learn how `new` and `delete` work, in order to use the smart pointers correctly.

Rust aims to be much *safer* than C or C++. Its smart pointers encapsulate **all** the details of how memory is handled at low-level. You only need to know how to allocate and deallocate raw memory if you're implementing a smart pointer yourself. Because of the way ownership is managed, you actually need to know a lot more details of the language to be able to write correct code. It can't be lesson one or two like it is in C or C++: it's a very advanced topic, and one many Rust programmers never need to learn about.

If you want to learn about how to allocate memory on the heap, the `Box` class is the place to start with that. In the Rust book, [the chapter about smart pointers](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch15-00-smart-pointers.html) **is** the chapter about memory allocation.

Comment: I perfectly understand that smart pointers are the way to go. But they're only containers which internally must use the aforementioned keywords. As I commented on Sébastien answer, what if I'm curious on implementing my own memory container?

Comment: @LppEdd Then you can look at the implementation of `Box` in the standard library if you like, but there's more in there than memory allocation. More so than in C++, Rust's `unsafe` code is very tricky to get right.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why but it seems that manual memory management is an hidden topic in Rust. While if I read a book about Cpp, it's the first thing I learn about.

Comment: "In modern C++, […] but you still need to call new to allocate the memory for your smart pointer to manage." -> No. In modern C++ people use [`std::make_unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) and [`std::make_shared`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared).

Comment: "if I read a book about Cpp, it's the first thing I learn about" How old is that book?

Comment: If you write `new` in C++11 (and beyond), you are asking for trouble. `std::vector` and `std::make_unique` should cover 99% of your use cases, `std::shared_ptr` 99% of the remaining cases. The odd use of `new` should be strictly reserved to implementing higher-level abstractions in foundational libraries.

Comment: Guys, I thought my question were simple and straightforward. We don't need to debate on Cpp standards. Anyway, I consider not knowing about direct memory allocation a big hole in the understanding of a language like these.

Comment: Btw, Stroustrup begin talking about pointers and memory management at page 171 of its own book.

Comment: Why wouldn't a beginner learn how to make his own smart pointer? As far as I know there is no option to manually free memory early, before Box pointer goes out of scope. Why not create your own smart pointer which works like Box, except you can free memory early if you want to. drop function of the Drop trait checks whether you have already freed the memory and if you did, then it doesn't free the memory again.